# Apache redirect to wrong Vhost while redirecting to https

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, redirect

## Problem

Accessing `studentmossa.domain.com`results in a redirect to `server.domain.com`.

## Short valuable information

I am running Fedora 31 (kernel 5.5.15-200.fc31.x86_64) with `Apache/2.4.43 (Fedora)`.

I have four websites (1 domain) managed by Apache's Virtual Host.

- `domain.com`
- `nextcloud.domain.com`
- `server.domain.com`
- `studentmossa.domain.com`

`apachectl configtest` gives:

Syntax OK

`httpd -S` gives:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/domain.com.conf:2)
         port 80 namevhost domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/domain.com.conf:2)
                 alias domain.com
         port 80 namevhost nextcloud.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/nextcloud.domain.com.conf:2)
                 alias nextcloud.domain.com
         port 80 namevhost studentmossa.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/server.domain.com.conf:2)
                 alias server.domain.com
         port 80 namevhost studentmossa.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/studentmossa.domain.com.conf:2)
                 alias studentmossa.domain.com
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/domain.com.conf:13)
         port 443 namevhost domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/domain.com.conf:13)
                 alias domain.com
         port 443 namevhost nextcloud.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/nextcloud.domain.com.conf:15)
                 alias nextcloud.domain.com
         port 443 namevhost studentmossa.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/server.domain.com.conf:11)
                 alias server.domain.com
         port 443 namevhost studentmossa.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
         port 443 namevhost studentmossa.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/studentmossa.domain.com.conf:16)
                 alias studentmossa.domain.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/etc/httpd/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "/etc/httpd/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

`server.domain.com`is a proxy from http://localhost/:19999 (It is a netdata setup)

Following is the configuration file for `server.domain.com`:

```
ServerName server.domain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias server.domain.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/server.domain.com/non_https_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/server.domain.com/non_https_access.log combined
        Redirect / https://server.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAlias server.domain.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/server.domain.com/non_https_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/server.domain.com/non_https_access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        <Proxy *>
                Require all granted
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:19999/" connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30 keepalive=on
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:19999/"

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.domain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.domain.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

and following is the configuration file for `studentmossa.domain.com`:

```
ServerName studentmossa.domain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias studentmossa.domain.com
        ServerName studentmossa.domain.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/studentmossa.domain.com/non_https_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/studentmossa.domain.com/non_https_access.log combined

        Redirect / https://studentmossa.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAlias studentmossa.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/studentmossa.domain.com/

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/studentmossa.domain.com/non_https_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/studentmossa.domain.com/non_https_access.log combined
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/studentmossa.domain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/studentmossa.domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

## What I have tried

I have tried changing the redirect rule, instead of `Redirect / https://studentmossa.domain.com` I have tried:

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =studentmossa.domain.com
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

on all vhosts. It gives the same result, of course changing the `SERVER_NAME`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why is the `ServerName` outside the `<VirtualHost>` blocks?

Comment: @Esa It was to my understanding that having it outside, ´<VirtualHost>` yet in the same file it would apply for both of them. However it is embarrassing to acknowledge by putting them inside the `<VirtualHost>` block it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the `ServerName` inside the `<VirtualHost>` blocks, it effectively solved the problem.

Comment: Directives outside the [configuration sections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html) applies to the entire server. This is also mentioned in the documentation for the [`ServerName` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername).